# How to return and print variable only when 'elif' was triggered - Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return

If I run this, it always prints "above 0.5" after 'elif' condition was met once. I want it only to return and print "above 0.5" only if 'elif' was currently triggered and run. Any suggestions?

```
def func(x):  
global return_value
    if x < 0.5: 
        pass
    elif x > 0.5: 
        return_value = "above 0.5"
return(return_value)

while True:        
    y = random.uniform(0, 1)
    text = func(y)
    print(text)
```

Comment: There are syntax problem in the shared code - (1) ```While``` should be ```while```  (2) the function will return ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'return_value' referenced before assignment```

Comment: Thanks, yes there are declarations omitted for simplicity.  I fixed it. My problem is that it always returns "above 0.5" after elif was triggered once.

Comment: @nolimits Why is that a problem? It says above 0.5 elif x is more than 0.5

Comment: @nolimits what do you want it to do instead

Comment: only to print the variable if elif was run. at the moment it always prints the variable after a while.

Comment: Why are you using a global variable for `return_variable`? And why are you passing on `x < 0.5`?

Answer (score 0):

I would write the code in this way, there is no need of that local variable within the function `func`

Also your while loop is eternal - there is `break` condition.

```
def func(x):    
    if x > 0.5: 
        return "above 0.5"
    else:
        return None

while True:  
    if (#some breaking condition#):
        break      
    y = random.uniform(0, 1)
    text = func(y)
    if text:
        print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps. In addition, I only want to print(text) when x>5 was met. Maybe something else is missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> The pass statement in Python is used when a statement is required syntactically but you do not want any command or code to execute.

So your codes **meet** your requirment: `print "above 0.5" only if 'elif' was currently triggered`

If you want different outputs for different inputs, use:

```
import time
import random

def func(x):    
    return_value = "below 0.5"
    if x < 0.5: 
        pass
    elif x > 0.5: 
        return_value = "above 0.5"
    return(return_value)

 
while True:        
    y = random.uniform(0, 1)
    text = func(y)
    print(text)
```